# How to promote feed items to front page? Drupal 7

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

Drupal 7.x, I use Feeds and Feeds News modules. I want promote feed items to front page (expanded content). I edited target feed and checked "Promoted to front page" option. Feed name and "Read more" links appears on front page, but only links, not feed content itself. Even if click on these links, this open empty "View" tab, not "View items" (where is feed content itself). How to place full feed content to the front page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always have the content type that you are importing to have the "Promoted to Front Page" option checked.

Logged in as an admin go to `admin/structure/types/manage/INSERT_CONTENT_TYPE_MACHINENAME_HERE`

and then click the Promoted to front page option

That should do it for you.. or else you need to mess with how your teasers are displayed on the front page.

Comment: Please a bit more details here: manage feed or feed-item? Manage fields or manage display, and where you mean to insert new type?

Comment: above is a URL, so assuming you have www.example.com, go to http://www.example.com/admin/structure/types/manage/INSERT_CONTENT_TYPE_MACHINENAME_HERE

Comment: to further add, when you are importing whatever you are importing with the Feeds module, you are importing it to a content type.  Change out the all caps in the URL with the machine name of the content type you are importing to.

Comment: It works now. I checked 'Promoted to front page' option in admin/structure/types/manage/feed-item. Also, does this works only for feed, that have 'Promoted to front page' option checked in ../node/8326/edit? The other feeds with unchecked option will not displayed on the front page?

Comment: Yea pretty much any feed item that you have already imported will need that box checked under the node/8326/edit page.. it might be easier to just delete the old content and re-import.

Comment: It pulls on the front page feed items from all feeds, not only feed items of the marked feed. I want to limit the feed items promoted to front page to one feed only.